# Copycat site causes disturbing images to turn up in image search

Tags: discussion, screen-scraping, copycat-sites

Today I tried out various images search sites and one of my test search terms was my own name.
What struck me was that the false positives were mostly the same regardless of the search site used. Also there were porn images amongst the false positives.

Under closer investigation I quickly found the source: `http://ja.w3support.net/`

It's a Stack Overflow scraper (with attribution) that translates the content to various languages. So far so good, nothing wrong with that I guess.

The problem is that they show images of random people (clothed and naked ones to say the least) as avatar next the answers.

I have no idea whether anything is wrong with that legally, but as they mention  "stackoverflow.com" as the source of their content, it certainly puts SO in a bad light.

**UPDATE 2011-04-05:**
On 2011-03-23 I phoned the hoster (hetzner.de). They told me to write to `abuse@hetzner.de`, which I did. I received an auto-reply the same day but nothing else happened since. I tried to reach their phone support (09831 610061) several times during their business hours (Mo-Fr 7:30-18:00 Uhr) but no one picked up. Sent them a follow-up email today.

**UPDATE 2011-12-11:**
The site has been down since about 2011-11-01.

Comment: Wow. That is *bizarre*

Comment: I don't see any attribution attached to the questions, only the answers.  Between that, and associating the answers with random gravatars instead of the real author's, I would say that they're not living up to the license terms.  Burninate with extreme prejudice!

Comment: Not only bizarre... but terrible.